# Rethrow Exception in a Coroutine Context

Tags: kotlin, exception, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I'm using intensively coroutine to create services, but I'm facing an issue about transforming Exception from inside my service to outside. Here is a synthesis of what I would like to do without Coroutine ([here is the full example in a playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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) :

```
class MyService {
    
    fun myBigComputation(type: MyServiceType) {
        try {
            for (i in (0..10_000)) {
                mySubComputation(type, i)
            }
        } catch (e: LowLevelException) {
            throw HighLevelException(type, e)
        }
    }
    
    private fun mySubComputation(type: MyServiceType, i: Int) {        
        ...
        // something bad happend 
        throw LowLevelException(type)            
    }
    
    ...
}
```

You can see that I'm transforming the **LowLevelException** to **HighLevelException**. What is the best way to do that in a coroutine context.

##### That is not working as LowLevelException fails all the structure until the supervisorScope [Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/3mWhHyOTO)

```
suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {
    
    val service = MyService()
    
    supervisorScope {
        for (type in MyService.MyServiceType.values()) {
            launch(CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e -> 
                if (e is HighLevelException) {
                    println("ERROR: ${e.message}")    
                }
            }) {
                service.myBigComputation(type)
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyService {
    
    suspend fun myBigComputation(type: MyServiceType) = coroutineScope {
        launch(CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e -> 
            if (e is LowLevelException) {
                throw HighLevelException(type, e)
            }
        }) {
            for (i in (0..10)) {
                mySubComputation(type, i)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private fun mySubComputation(type: MyServiceType, i: Int) {
        if (i < 5 || type != MyServiceType.type1) {
            print(".")
        } else {
            // something bad happend
            println("something bad happened but exception kill all")
            throw LowLevelException(type)            
        }
    }
    
    class LowLevelException(val type: MyServiceType): Exception()
    
    enum class MyServiceType {
        type1,
        type2,
        type3
    }
}

class HighLevelException(val type: MyService.MyServiceType, e: Exception): Exception("Exception for type $type", e)
```

##### I did that, but I'm pretty sure that there is a better way, no ? [Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/TwLmtqE9Q)

```
suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {
    
    val service = MyService()
    
    supervisorScope {
        for (type in MyService.MyServiceType.values()) {
            launch(CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e -> 
                if (e is HighLevelException) {
                    println("ERROR: ${e.message}")    
                }
            }) {
                service.myBigComputation(type)
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyService {
    
    suspend fun myBigComputation(type: MyServiceType) = supervisorScope {
        launch(CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e -> 
            if (e is LowLevelException) {
                throw HighLevelException(type, e)
            }
        }) {
            for (i in (0..10)) {
                mySubComputation(type, i)
            }
        }
    }
    
    //...
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to catch `e: LowLevelException` in that example?

Comment: I edited your question to put your code from the playground in it. Questions and answers on this site are not supposed to rely fully on another website to be coherent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over-complicating it by trying to use CoroutineExceptionHandler for this. CoroutineExceptionHandler is for uncaught exceptions. By the time it is called, your coroutine has already thrown and failed. It is intended to be a very high level behavior, kind of like `uncaughtExceptionHandler` in Java, if you're familiar with that.

But also, you're attaching your CoroutineExceptionHandler to child coroutines. Setting a CoroutineExceptionHandler on a *child* coroutine has no effect, because it is only for handling uncaught exceptions, and child coroutines propagate exceptions to their parents. See the second paragraph [in the documentation here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exception-handling.html#coroutineexceptionhandler) for the explanation.

So your code should look more like:

```
suspend fun main() {
    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e -> 
        if (e is HighLevelException) {
            println("ERROR: ${e.message}")    
        }
    }
    runBlocking(handler) {
        val service = MyService()
        supervisorScope {
            for (type in MyService.MyServiceType.values()) {
                launch {
                    service.myBigComputation(type)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyService {
    
    suspend fun myBigComputation(type: MyServiceType) {
        try {
            for (i in (0..10)) {
                mySubComputation(type, i)
            }
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            throw if (e is LowLevelException) {
                HighLevelException(type, e)
            } else {
                e
            }
        }
    }

    //...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer ! [So I miss something about coroutine behavior about exception and try catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75629494/why-try-catch-behavior-is-different-in-a-coroutine-scope-and-in-a-simple-suspend)