# Why try/catch behavior is different in a coroutine scope and in a simple suspending function (Kotlin)?

Tags: kotlin, exception, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

As I tried to managed the [rethrow in a coroutine context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75628160/rethrow-exception-in-a-coroutine-context?noredirect=1#comment133424731_75628160), I finally understood that in suspending function [we can use try/catch as usual](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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) (thanks @Tenfour04).

```
fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    launch {
        doAction()
    }

    launch {
        delay(2000)
        println("Printed2")
    }
}

suspend fun doAction() {
     try {
        delay(1000)
        throw Error("Some error")
    } catch (e: Throwable) { // nope, does not help here
        println("Printed1")
    }
}
// Printed1
// Printed2
```

But what was confusing me (and make me use badly the CoroutineExceptionHandler) is [in the following code the try/catch is not working as usual](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS44LjEwIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiaW1wb3J0IGtvdGxpbnguY29yb3V0aW5lcy4qXG5pbXBvcnQga290bGlueC5jb3JvdXRpbmVzLnJ1bkJsb2NraW5nXG5cbmZ1biBtYWluKCk6IFVuaXQgPSBydW5CbG9ja2luZyB7XG4gICAgLy8gRG9uJ3Qgd3JhcCBpbiBhIHRyeS1jYXRjaCBoZXJlLiBJdCB3aWxsIGJlIGlnbm9yZWQuXG4gICAgdHJ5IHtcbiAgICAgICAgbGF1bmNoIHtcbiAgICAgICAgICAgIGRlbGF5KDEwMDApXG4gICAgICAgICAgICB0aHJvdyBFcnJvcihcIlNvbWUgZXJyb3JcIilcbiAgICAgICAgfVxuICAgIH0gY2F0Y2ggKGU6IFRocm93YWJsZSkgeyAvLyBub3BlLCBkb2VzIG5vdCBoZWxwIGhlcmVcbiAgICAgICAgcHJpbnRsbihcIldpbGwgbm90IGJlIHByaW50ZWRcIilcbiAgICB9XG5cbiAgICBsYXVuY2gge1xuICAgICAgICBkZWxheSgyMDAwKVxuICAgICAgICBwcmludGxuKFwiV2lsbCBub3QgYmUgcHJpbnRlZFwiKVxuICAgIH1cbn1cbiJ9), as the exception kills the coroutine :

```
fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    // Don't wrap in a try-catch here. It will be ignored.
    try {
        launch {
            delay(1000)
            throw Error("Some error")
        }
    } catch (e: Throwable) { // nope, does not help here
        println("Will not be printed")
    }

    launch {
        delay(2000)
        println("Will not be printed")
    }
}
// Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Some error...
```

In both case, we are in a coroutine context. The difference is :

- the first one has not a coroutine scope as this
- the second one as coroutine scope as this

I'm not very clear of why the try/catch behavior is different in the both cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I understood. This is because the try/catch is outside of coroutine. If I change the try/catch and the launch, the exception not kill the coroutine.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    // Don't wrap in a try-catch here. It will be ignored.
    launch {
        try {
            delay(1000)
            throw Error("Some error")
        } catch (e: Throwable) { // nope, does not help here
            println("Will not be printed")
        }
    }

    launch {
        delay(2000)
        println("Will not be printed")
    }
}
```

Sorry, it was so evident.

Tenfour04 told me in the previous question, but I did’t get that.

Stackoverflow is a good therapy :)

Comment: Also, `launch` and `async` behave differently. With `async`, the thrown exception from inside the coroutine never does anything until you call `await()` on the Deferred.

Comment: To be honest, it has nothing to do with coroutine contexts, scopes, etc. This code simply doesn't at all run inside the try...catch block. Only because some code block is visually placed inside another, doesn't mean it runs inside it. We can create a lambda for many different reasons: to store it, to run it later, to run it now, but from another place, etc. `launch()` is the latter. It will be the same if you use `thread {}`, `executor.submit {}`, or `someService.registerCallback {}`. In these cases the passed lambda is not invoked by us directly.